# Does gbm package in R produce predicted value from train set?

Tags: r

I am using gbm package to create a simple gradient boosting machine model. I would like to calculate some statistics from predicted vs. actual (such as GINI ratio, SSE). I read the vignette as well as manual, but could not find out where to get predicted values from output of this procedure. (Of course I can use gbm to predict on the train set, but it takes me a long time to run .predict).

Comment: you won't use predict.gbm function?

Comment: Hi agstudy, I will use it. I just don't want to use it on my train set just to get predicted, which I think should be created by gbm

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help  you:

```
 pretty.gbm.tree(gbm1, i.tree=1) ## object gbm1 hast a list trees

 SplitVar SplitCodePred LeftNode RightNode MissingNode ErrorReduction Weight    Prediction
0        2  0.000000e+00        1         5           9      217.27619    250  2.074694e-04
1        1  1.232392e+00        2         3           4       30.95838     83 -5.554687e-03
2       -1 -7.445325e-03       -1        -1          -1        0.00000     60 -7.445325e-03
3       -1 -6.225881e-04       -1        -1          -1        0.00000     23 -6.225881e-04
4       -1 -5.554687e-03       -1        -1          -1        0.00000     83 -5.554687e-03
5        1  8.915513e-01        6         7           8       25.62508     89  5.689724e-03
6       -1  2.914792e-03       -1        -1          -1        0.00000     43  2.914792e-03
7       -1  8.283682e-03       -1        -1          -1        0.00000     46  8.283682e-03
8       -1  5.689724e-03       -1        -1          -1        0.00000     89  5.689724e-03
9       -1  8.360223e-05       -1        -1          -1        0.00000     78  8.360223e-05
```